# Multiple NPE errors in Android code

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am new to Android programming and haven't used Java for a long time so excuse me if this is noobish.
I'm getting several NPE errors in the debug log, but the program does seem to be running, all I intended it to do was to connect to a PHP web service (self-hosted) and output some JSON values to the display.
Sorry I know the code is messy, I will tidy it up if it helps.

Just to re-iterate, the code is doing what it is supposed to, i.e. output 'Froyo Android 2.2' to the Android emulator. I just want to make sure I know why these errors are appearing.

```
package com.sft.androidwebservtest.app;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String jsonResult;
    //private String url = "http://cpriyankara.coolpage.biz/employee_details.php";
    private String url = "http://192.168.0.2/testws.php";
    //private ListView listView;

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //
        //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);

        accessWebService();
        //
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //
    // Async Task to access the web
    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            }

            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ListDrwaer();
        }
    }// end async task

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        // passes values for the urls string array
        task.execute(new String[] { url });
    }

    // build hash set for list view
    //public void ListDrwaer1() {
    //  List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    //
    //  try {
    //      JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
    //      JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("emp_info");
    //
    //      for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    //          JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    //          String name = jsonChildNode.optString("employee name");
    //          String number = jsonChildNode.optString("employee no");
    //          String outPut = name + "-" + number;
    //          employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
    //      }
    //  } catch (JSONException e) {
    //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
    //              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //  }
    //
    //  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
    //          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    //          new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    //  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    //}

    public void ListDrwaer() {
        try {

            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

            String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
            String version = jsonResponse.getString("version");
            textView.setText(name + " - " + version);

            //JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("emp_info");

            //for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            //  JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            //  String name = jsonChildNode.optString("employee name");
            //  String number = jsonChildNode.optString("employee no");
            //  String outPut = name + "-" + number;
            //  employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
            //}
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
        //      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        //      new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        //listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    }

    //private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
    //  HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //  employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
    //  return employeeNameNo;
    //}
}
```

Errors in debug log:

```
03-14 16:34:34.750      895-895/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-14 16:34:38.330      895-895/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 62K, 5% free 2958K/3088K, paused 142ms, total 158ms
03-14 16:34:38.360      895-895/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.558MB for 635812-byte allocation
03-14 16:34:38.500      895-904/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3576K/3712K, paused 139ms, total 139ms
03-14 16:34:39.960      895-895/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8d3b4f0, tid 895
03-14 16:34:40.150      895-895/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 16:34:40.170      895-895/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-14 16:34:40.200      895-895/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-14 17:44:49.914    1159-1159/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3b13b90)
03-14 17:44:49.924    1159-1159/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sft.androidwebservtest.app, PID: 1159
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sft.androidwebservtest.app/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1883)
            at com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:53)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 17:47:08.534    1205-1205/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-14 17:47:08.534    1205-1205/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3b13b90)
03-14 17:47:08.644    1205-1205/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sft.androidwebservtest.app, PID: 1205
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sft.androidwebservtest.app/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1883)
            at com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:53)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 17:47:12.024    1205-1205/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1205 SIG: 9
03-14 17:53:34.054    1250-1250/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 70K, 5% free 2958K/3096K, paused 59ms, total 62ms
03-14 17:53:34.074    1250-1250/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.558MB for 635812-byte allocation
03-14 17:53:34.124    1250-1259/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3576K/3720K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
03-14 17:53:34.534    1250-1250/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8e16df8, tid 1250
03-14 17:53:34.814    1250-1250/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 17:53:34.824    1250-1250/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-14 17:53:36.104    1250-1250/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-14 17:53:36.104    1250-1250/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3b13b90)
03-14 17:53:36.144    1250-1250/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sft.androidwebservtest.app, PID: 1250
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity.ListDrwaer(MainActivity.java:179)
            at com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:133)
            at com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:93)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 17:53:39.664    1250-1250/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1250 SIG: 9
03-14 17:54:22.124    1299-1299/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 74K, 5% free 2958K/3100K, paused 50ms, total 53ms
03-14 17:54:22.134    1299-1299/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.558MB for 635812-byte allocation
03-14 17:54:22.244    1299-1308/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3576K/3724K, paused 108ms, total 108ms
03-14 17:54:22.534    1299-1299/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8d3b4f0, tid 1299
03-14 17:54:22.694    1299-1299/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 17:54:22.704    1299-1299/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-14 17:54:23.324    1299-1299/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-14 17:54:23.324    1299-1299/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3b13b90)
03-14 17:54:23.384    1299-1299/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sft.androidwebservtest.app, PID: 1299
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity.ListDrwaer(MainActivity.java:179)
            at com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:133)
            at com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:93)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 17:54:28.174    1299-1299/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1299 SIG: 9
03-14 18:01:53.764    1347-1347/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 5% free 2958K/3104K, paused 57ms, total 60ms
03-14 18:01:53.784    1347-1347/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.558MB for 635812-byte allocation
03-14 18:01:53.834    1347-1356/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3576K/3728K, paused 49ms, total 49ms
03-14 18:01:54.214    1347-1347/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8e170a8, tid 1347
03-14 18:01:54.324    1347-1347/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 18:01:54.354    1347-1347/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-14 18:01:55.244    1347-1347/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-14 18:01:55.244    1347-1347/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3b13b90)
03-14 18:01:55.254    1347-1347/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sft.androidwebservtest.app, PID: 1347
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity.ListDrwaer(MainActivity.java:179)
            at com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:133)
            at com.sft.androidwebservtest.app.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:93)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 18:01:59.114    1347-1347/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1347 SIG: 9
03-14 18:05:19.344    1396-1396/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 82K, 5% free 2958K/3108K, paused 50ms, total 52ms
03-14 18:05:19.354    1396-1396/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.558MB for 635812-byte allocation
03-14 18:05:19.404    1396-1405/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3576K/3732K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
03-14 18:05:19.854    1396-1396/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8cd4a08, tid 1396
03-14 18:05:19.964    1396-1396/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 18:05:19.984    1396-1396/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-14 18:07:16.444    1438-1438/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 85K, 5% free 2958K/3112K, paused 61ms, total 64ms
03-14 18:07:16.454    1438-1438/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.558MB for 635812-byte allocation
03-14 18:07:16.504    1438-1447/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3576K/3736K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
03-14 18:07:16.814    1438-1438/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8d3b4f0, tid 1438
03-14 18:07:16.944    1438-1438/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 18:07:16.954    1438-1438/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-14 18:11:11.324    1482-1482/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8e12550, tid 1482
03-14 18:11:11.464    1482-1482/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 18:11:11.504    1482-1482/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-14 18:11:12.784    1482-1495/com.sft.androidwebservtest.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 255K, 10% free 3027K/3348K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
```

Comment: What is at line 53? Looks like something there is `null`. Looks like `output` isn't a valid `id` in your `layout` file. And since you never reference that `TextView` it doesn't crash. If you were to, say, try and set text to it I believe it would crash.

Comment: Your stack trace shows a constructor at line 53, but there is not one in your posted source code.

Comment: `private TextView textView;`

< This is at line 53. Also, if the text I set to the textview should fail, then why does the emulator output the correct text? This is why I am confused, it works in spite of throwing all these errors.

Comment: What is at line 179? And have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: How do I clean my project? I'm using Android Studio 0.5.1 (I kept getting recommended to use it because it supposedly is what Android coding is moving towards.). Is there a specific way to do this? Also line 179 is `String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");`. And just to make it easier for everyone, the other errors are as follows: line 133 `@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {` line 93: `//
    // Async Task to access the web
    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {`

Comment: Sorry for the extra characters in the lines with errors, sometimes the error starts where there is a comment for some reason, so I included the comment down to where the method declaration begins.

Comment: I ran 'Re-arrange code' and 'Reformat Code' in Android Studio. I'm no longer getting the errors. Now I don't understand if it was only an Android Studio problem or a code problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reformatted and refactored code from the menu options in Android studio 0.5.1 and it seems to have stopped the errors from being displayed.